# Parse error while using grunt-contrib-htmlmin?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-htmlmin

I am trying to minify HTML files using `grunt-contrib-htmlmin`.However I keep getting a `Parse Error`.Below is the `command line` response.

```
Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task
Warning: template/applications/applications.html
Parse Error: <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" data-i18n="[title
]Reset_filter" , data-bind="click:function(){clearfilter('jqxgridApplications')}
"><i class="icon-reset-filter"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" da
 ta-toggle="modal" data-target="#hideShowColumns" ,data-i18n="[title]show_hide" d
ata-bind="click: function () {openPopup('modelShowHideCol','jqxgridApplications'
)}"><i class="icon-hide-column"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" da
ta-i18n="[title]exportToXls" data-bind="click:function(){exportToExcel(true,'jqx
gridApplications')}"><i class="icon-export-excel"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" da
ta-i18n="[title]refresh_data" data-bind="click:function(){refreshGrid('jqxgridAp
plications')}"><i class="icon-spinner9"></i></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="grid-area">
                        <div id="jqxgridApplications" style="width:100%">
                        </div>
                        <div id="pagerDivApplication"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="applicationModel
" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLab
el" aria-hidden="true">
                <div data-bind="if: templateFlag">
                    <div data-bind='component:observableModelPopup'>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div> Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Even if I use `--force` the error is same? **Any help is really appreciated.**

below is how I have defined the `htmlmin` task.

```
htmlmin: {
dist: {
  files: [{
     expand: true,
     cwd: 'template',
     src: '**/*.html',
     dest: 'template_dist/'
   }]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two anchor elements have an extra comma in between the data attributes. The first has a comma after the `data-i18n` attribute, and the second has a comma after `data-target`. Try removing the commas, and see if the parse error goes away.